# How to Integrate n genius payment gateway to Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Please Guide me How to integrate ngenius-payment gateway to laravel app 
Their documentation not enough to integrate with laravel.
i am planing to choose with making payments from their websites, and return back to us with a return URL.

### Below php code i got from their documentation. but confused to integrate in laravel.

```
 <?php



$postData = new StdClass(); 

$postData->action = "SALE"; 
$postData->amount = new StdClass();
$postData->amount->currencyCode = "AED"; 
$postData->amount->value = 100; 

 $outlet = "my-oulet-id";
$token = token_key(); //to ken generatig

$json = json_encode($postData);
$ch = curl_init(); 


   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-gateway-uat.ngenius- 
   payments.com/transactions/outlets/".$outlet."/orders'); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
   "Authorization: Bearer ".$token, 
   "Content-Type: application/vnd.ni-payment.v2+json", 
    "Accept: application/vnd.ni-payment.v2+json")); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);   
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json); 

  $output = json_decode(curl_exec($ch)); 
  $order_reference = $output->reference; 
   $order_paypage_url = $output->_links->payment->href; 

  curl_close ($ch);

function token_key(){
$apikey = "api-key";        // enter your API key here
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://identity-uat.ngenius- 
payments.com/auth/realms/ni/protocol/openid-connect/token"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
"Authorization: Basic ".$apikey, 
"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  
http_build_query(array('grant_type' => 
'client_credentials'))); 
$output = json_decode(curl_exec($ch)); 
$access_token = $output->access_token;
return $access_token;
 }
?>
```

Comment: I had a quick look at their documentation, and it looks pretty good to me. If you are having trouble with this and want our help, then you need to make an effort and _properly_ describe your problem / issue.

Comment: I iam looking for

1.Which is the link i have to redirect the user for making payment
2.what are the details i have to pass with that payment url.

Comment: @hemil bro if you can use another gateway then do use razorpay as it is the easiest to integrate in laravel

Comment: @khalid khan .. that i know .. but client forcing me on this  that's why...

Comment: Oh okay. I thought it's your personal project that's why i suggested you razorpay

Comment: okay thanks for guiding me

Answer (score 1):

```
****Below Code May Help You .. It works for me Up to their payment window****
public function make_payment(){

$outletRef   = "your-outlet-id";                                                                       // set your outlet reference/ID value here (example only)
$apikey      = "your-application-key";       // set your service account API key (example only)


$idServiceURL  = "https://identity-uat.ngenius-payments.com/auth/realms/ni/protocol/openid-connect/token";           // set the identity service URL (example only)
$txnServiceURL = "https://api-gateway-uat.ngenius-payments.com/transactions/outlets/".$outletRef."/orders";             // set the transaction service URL (example only)


$tokenHeaders  = array("Authorization: Basic ".$apikey, "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
$tokenResponse = invokeCurlRequest("POST", $idServiceURL, $tokenHeaders, http_build_query(array('grant_type' => 'client_credentials')));
$tokenResponse = json_decode($tokenResponse);

$access_token = $tokenResponse->access_token;

$order = new StdClass();

$order->action = "AUTH";                                        // Transaction mode ("AUTH" = authorize only, no automatic settle/capture, "SALE" = authorize + automatic settle/capture)
$order->amount->currencyCode = "AED";                           // Payment currency ('AED' only for now)
$order->amount->value = 01*100;                                   // Minor units (1000 = 10.00 AED)
$order->language = "en";                                        // Payment page language ('en' or 'ar' only)
$order->merchantOrderReference = time();                                        // Payment page language ('en' or 'ar' only)
//$order->merchantAttributes->redirectUrl = "http://premizer.com/test/pp.php";     // A redirect URL to a page on your site to return the customer to
//$order->merchantAttributes->redirectUrl = "http://192.168.0.111:8080/n-genius/pp.php";     // A redirect URL to a page on your site to return the customer to
$order->merchantAttributes->redirectUrl = "your page url wich u want to redirect after payment success"; 
// A redirect URL to a page on your site to return the customer to
//$order->merchantAttributes->redirectUrl = "http:// 192.168.0.111:8080/n-genius/pp.php";     // A redirect URL to a page on your site to return the customer to
$order = json_encode($order);  


$orderCreateHeaders  = array("Authorization: Bearer ".$access_token, "Content-Type: application/vnd.ni-payment.v2+json", "Accept: application/vnd.ni-payment.v2+json");
$orderCreateResponse = invokeCurlRequest("POST", $txnServiceURL, $orderCreateHeaders, $order);

$orderCreateResponse = json_decode($orderCreateResponse);
$paymentLink           = $orderCreateResponse->_links->payment->href;     // the link to the payment page for redirection (either full-page redirect or iframe)
$orderReference      = $orderCreateResponse->reference;              // the reference to the order, which you should store in your records for future interaction with this order

header("Location: ".$paymentLink);                              // execute redirect
//die();

function invokeCurlRequest($type, $url, $headers, $post) {

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);     

    if ($type == "POST") {

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

    }

    $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
    // print_r($server_output);
    // exit();
    curl_close ($ch);

    return $server_output;

}

}
```

> Email them to get a valid test card details .. and check . all the very best .yo  you

Comment: hello,i have same issue getting null response on browser but when i hit this api via postman i got response,please help

Comment: issue may be with header value passed please cross check

Comment: thanks for your response, I checked them even copy same curl from postman but didnot work.

Comment: incase i want to change the currencycode to USD instead of AED i get error of "No payment method available for currency" what will i do